# Wrong Panel content height with ui.table (visibleRowCountMode="Auto")

Tags: sapui5

I want to have a layout which has a fixed size panel with a form at the top and a panel with a grid which takes the remaining space at the bottom. I have managed that the panels have the correct size - so the section html tag of the grid's panel has 100% and correctly spans but the height of the nested div for the content is calculated to 0px.

What definition is necessary or missing so that the grid takes the complete remaining space?

```
<mvc:View
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" 
        xmlns:t="sap.ui.table"

        height="100%">
        <l:FixFlex class="fixFlexFixedSize" fixContentSize="100px">
            <l:fixContent>
                <Panel class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Form" level="H2" />
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <content>
                        <f:Form editable="true">
                            <f:layout>
                                <f:ResponsiveGridLayout 
                                        labelSpanL="2" 
                                        labelSpanM="2" 
                                        emptySpanL="1" 
                                        emptySpanM="1" 
                                        columnsL="2" 
                                        columnsM="2" />
                            </f:layout>
                            <f:formContainers>
                                <f:FormContainer>
                                    <f:formElements>
                                        <f:FormElement label="Lastname">
                                            <f:fields>
                                                <Input id="lastname" />
                                            </f:fields>
                                        </f:FormElement>
                                    </f:formElements>
                                </f:FormContainer>
                                <f:FormContainer>
                                    <f:FormElement label="Firstname">
                                        <f:fields>
                                            <Input  id="firstname" />
                                        </f:fields>
                                    </f:FormElement>
                                </f:FormContainer>
                            </f:formContainers>
                        </f:Form>
                    </content>
                </Panel>
                </l:fixContent>
            <l:flexContent>
                <Panel height="100%" class="sapUiNoContentPadding">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Grid" level="H2" />
                            <ToolbarSpacer />
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://add" text="new" press="newEntry" />
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <content>
                        <t:Table 
                            rows="{entries>/result}"
                            enableSelectAll="false"
                            selectionMode="None"
                            visibleRowCountMode="Auto"
                            height="100%">
                            <t:columns>
                                <t:Column width="5rem" >
                                    <Label text="{i18n>entrieslist.column.name}" />
                                    <t:template>
                                        <Link text="{entries>lastname}" press="showDetailsPage"/>
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                                <t:Column width="5rem" >
                                    <t:template>
                                        <Text text="{entries>firstname}" />
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                                <t:Column width="11rem" sorted="true" sortProperty="{entries>telephone} ">
                                    <Label text="{i18n>entrieslist.column.number}" />
                                    <t:template>
                                        <Text text="{entries>telephone}" />
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                                <t:Column width="11rem"  >
                                    <Label text="{i18n>entrieslist.column.street}" />
                                    <t:template>
                                        <Text text="{entries>street}" />
                                    </t:template>
                                </t:Column>
                            </t:columns>
                        </t:Table>
                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </l:flexContent>
        </l:FixFlex>            
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I encounter a bug or the usecase is just not supported. My sample is in a view accessed via routing. When I navigate from the default page the sizeing works - if jump to the page directly via the url hash it fails (as described above). In addition if the grid is rendered and the window is resized the panel height is not recalculated.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I managed to have a workaround in chrome with style="height:100%" for the content, but in firefox nothing seem to  work.

Comment: This seems to have been caused by a race condition which made the resizing sometimes fail. I was able to reproduce the fail only a few times in the very old SAPUI5 versions (using now-deprecated APIs). **Now the issue is no longer reproducible.** Here is a sample with the latest version: https://embed.plnkr.co/wnCV0fDnyJR2BQj9?show=view%2FApp.view.xml,preview. Since this issue is no longer reproducible, I'm voting to close this question.